# Using VOUT to Power Up a DC-DC Switching Regulator

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, constant-current, texas-instruments, constant-voltage

I am trying to use LM5117 to convert 36V (VIN) to 32V (VOUT) for constant current constant voltage application. It seems the datasheet is saying if the VIN > 14.5V I can use VOUT with a Zener diode  (see the attached picture) to power up the DC-DC chip as well. How is this possible since you need the VCC (VCC has to be between 5.5V and 14V) to first power up the chip first. It almost feels like the "chicken or the egg" paradox.

My question was can you use VOUT as the supply voltage for a voltage regulator?

[image]

Comment: Please draw a schematic (with the built in tool preferably, editing the question) of what you intend

Comment: @VoltageSpike my question was can you use VOUT as the supply voltage for a voltage regulator? You can see that in the schematic shown in the question (from the datasheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the zener diode is for a reference for the HB pin, Vcc in this part is an output not an input. Vin is the input.

Comment: Understood. I think I read the datasheet wrong.